# Transformar variável em array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma variável que chama todos os nomes de pessoas.

```
var nome = "João Miguel Pedro";
```

Como que eu faço para que ela se transforme no seguinte array:

```
var nome1 = ["João","Miguel","Pedro"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro caso, uma opção é usar o [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para separar por espaço. Veja:

```js
var nome = "João Miguel Pedro"

var nome1 = nome.split(" ");

console.log(nome1);
```

Ou você pode fazer um *regex* para fazer um `split()` por letras maiúsculas, como você questionou nos comentários. Veja:

```js
var nome = "JoãoMiguelPedro"

var nome1 = nome.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);

console.log(nome1);
```

Comment: Ok, mas se no caso não tiver espaço?

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca por exemplo se tiver virgula, da pra fazer da mesma forma. `var nome = "João,Miguel,Pedro"` ai seria desta forma: `nome.split(",")`... Caso contrário, você teria que detalhar melhor seu problema pra gente tentar resolver.

Comment: O problema é que a variável traz: JoãoMiguelPedro, sem espaços sem nada. Eu só preciso saber como que eu faço para pegar estes valores. Se eu usar o split ele não vai pegar

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca no seu exemplo só tinha por espaço. Editei a pergunta fazendo um split com letras maiúsculas.

Comment: Obrigado agora deu certo

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca se quiser validar a resposta, fique a vontade. =D